# Angular Js DatePicker not showing anything in the input but when you click the calendar popup is correct

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using Angular 1.5.2, UI-Bootstrap 1.2.5, Bootstrap css 3.3.6

So my json data comes in with the date as a string (I can't help or change that).

```
"start": "2014-06-12"
```

I use moment to convert to a date.
//part of a larger object returned from an ajax call

```
$scope.item=data[0];
$scope.item.startM=moment($scope.item.start);
$scope.item.endM=moment($scope.item.end);
```

In the {{item}} I see visually on screen
    "start":"2014-06-12"
    "startM":"2014-06-12T04:00:00.000Z"

In the console I can display the 
    startM:o
_d:Thu Jun 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
_f:"YYYY-MM-DD"
_i:"2014-06-12"
_isAMomentObject:true
_isUTC:false
_isValid:true
_locale:A

The input field is blank????

When I click on the calendar to see the date it's selected the correct date and will display properly in the input field if I select it.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="item.end" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" /><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>     </span>

$scope.dateOptions = {
formatYear: 'yy',
maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
minDate: new Date(),
startingDay: 1
```

};

```
$scope.formats = ['yyyy-MM-dd','dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
```

$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

I know I'm not providing much detail but I'm struggling to understand why the calendar knows the correct date but the input box doesn't...

Comment: what is interesting about this is that if I change the code to...
<input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" ng-model="item.endM" is-open="popup2.opened"  close-text="Close" datepicker-options="dateOptions" datepicker-popup="{{format}}">
then the date will appear but the pop up won't??
the change is 
uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}
to 
datepicker-popup="{{format}}

As you can tell I'm a novice at this...this may be getting off track but I wonder if it's related to https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4616

Answer (score 1):

You have `minDate: new Date()`. That is today, but then you are attempting to set the date to June 12, 2014 which is less than the minimum date you have specified. That's probably why it's blank.

Comment: Hi Lex - unfortunately that's not it (I tried removing and then also editing the min/max to see if any consequence) but no change. The input field is blank yet the calendar popup is correct. What's bizarre is that I have it working in another similar application - granted they are using different versions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the uib-datepicker-popup appears to require a date generated by uibDateParser. You need to do something like this instead of using moment.js:

```
$scope.item.start = uibDateParser.parse($scope.item.start, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

I can't tell you why it shows correctly in the popup but not in the text box, but it is what it is at this point I'm sure.